# Pivot tables without aggregation?

Tags: excel, date, group-by, pivot-without-aggregate

I have a list of items - each item has a title, plus a bunch of attributes, including a date.

If I drop the date into the row box of a pivot table, then group it, and drop the title below - so I have Years, Quarters, Created On, Title, I get a nice list of all the titles in my data, grouped by year, quarter and month.

But I want to also display all the other attributes next to the title of each one - all the associated data for each row.  With the textural ones, I don't want to count them - I just want to list the entire data set, but grouped by date.  If I add them to the other pivot table boxes it starts doing the usual counting...

It would be nice to have all the extra filtering power of pivot tables, but am I making this too hard?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give an example of your table/code. 
Pictures/Code make it easier to see structures.

Answer (score 0):

**To display text data, you will need to use the data label feature.**
Non pivotable text aggregation is easily accomplished in M code in power query [One of my posts](https://Rejoin%20=%20(LineList%20as%20list)%20as%20text%20=%3E%20Text.Combine(List.Transform(LineList,%20each%20Text.Combine(%7B_,%20%22#(lf)%22%7D)))).
[image: Data labels in excel pivot chart]